# javascript loader in php foreach

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a little javascript loader. My code:

```
<?
//COUNT TOTAL PURCHASE INVOICES
$i = 0;
foreach($xml->tr as $purchase) 
{
    $i++;
}
$steps = 100 / $i;

$steps = str_replace(',', '.', $steps);


foreach($xml->tr as $purchase) 
{   
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        var loaderValue = $("#loaderValue").val();
        newLoaderValue = parseFloat(loaderValue) + parseFloat("<?=$steps?>");

        $("#loaderValue").val(newLoaderValue);
        $(".connect_loader").width(newLoaderValue+"%");
    });
    </script>
    <?
}
?>
```

The script worked but the problem is that the javascript runs after php is ready so the loader is in one step at 100%.

Is there another simple way to do this?

Comment: it is required to use '$(document).ready(function() ..'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing.

You have to know that the PHP is used server side and the javascript client side.

> The script worked but the problem is that the javascript runs after
>   php is ready so the loader is in one step at 100%.

So this behavior is normal.

The best way to do what you want to do is to make a Javascript function which do an Ajax call and increment your loader depends on the result of the function.

Comment: Yes that's what I found out. That's why I asked for another solution.

Comment: So when I use an Ajax call (in the foreach) to a page with the loader function that will work?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not visible to the client. The server will process the PHP part of your code and generate a html page which the client will see.
This means you cannot use PHP during runtime.
Try to store whatever values you need into Javascript variables and use those instead.
A simple way to understand this is to view page source on your webpage... You can see the resultant html code.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this works.

```
<?php
//COUNT TOTAL PURCHASE INVOICES
$i = 0;
foreach($xml->tr as $purchase) 
{
    $i++;
}
$steps = 100 / $i;

$steps = str_replace(',', '.', $steps);
?>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        for(var x = 0; x <= <?php echo $i ?>; x++){
            var loaderValue = $("#loaderValue").val();
            newLoaderValue = parseFloat(loaderValue) + parseFloat("<?php echo $steps ?>");

            $("#loaderValue").val(newLoaderValue);
            $(".connect_loader").width(newLoaderValue + "%");
        }
    });
</script>
```